# Python regex for finding dots in email address

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a function that will do this:

- Make sure there isn't a `.` at the beginning or at the end of a domain.
- Make sure there aren't two `.` in the domain.
- Make sure there is at least one `.` in the domain.

Like blabla@outlook.com, it's suppose to make sure it isn't:

```
.blabla@outlook.com.
blabla@outlook..com
```

and that it is blabla@outlook.com

Here is my code for correcting domain:

```
import re
def correct_domain(domain):

    if re.search(r'^\.|.$', domain) and re.search(r'\.\.', domain):
        return False
    else re.search(r'\.', domain):
        return True
```

Comment: Your `else` should be changed to `elif`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.$` should be `\.$`, and `and` should be `or`. The `else` should be `elif`, and you should add a final `else` clause to handle domains with no dots at all.

```
if re.search(r'^\.|\.$', domain) or re.search(r'\.\.', domain):
    return False
elif re.search(r'\.', domain):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I suggest reorganizing the logic a bit. You can combine the first two reges, for one. You could do it all in one `return` statement.

```
return re.search(r'\.', domain) and not re.search(r'^\.|.$|\.\.', domain):
```

You could also do these specific checks without regexes, which would be more readable:

```
return '.' in domain and not \
    (domain.startswith('.') or domain.endswith('.') or '..' in domain)
```

Comment: I have this function already
def construct_email(name, domain):
    return name + "@" + domain

and i need a function called correct_domain(domain)
that checks that the email thats been input in "construct_email(name,domain)" is correct.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy enough to do without a regex:

```
(domain[0] != '.' != domain[-1] and 
 '..' not in domain and 
 '.'  in domain)
```

If you want to exclude cases with two or more periods in general you can try:

```
domain[0]  != '.' != domain[-1] and domain.count('.') == 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't that allow something with two non-adjacent periods to get by, as long as neither was at the start or end?

Comment: @StephenTG I thought the OP wanted to only exclude cases with two consecutive periods, did I misread the question?

Comment: All the OP said was that they don't want two periods, although the only example with two periods has two consecutive ones.

Comment: @StephenTG Ok, I added another approach to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `\` before the second dot; change the `and` to an `or`:

```
if re.search(r'^\.|\.$', domain) or re.search(r'\.\.', domain):
```